# Why are my line break tags not resolving?

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I'm getting text from the document using

```
var doc = context.document;
var originalRange = doc.body;
originalRange.load("text");
return context.sync()
  .then(function () {
    // have some fun with the text
  }
```

I then send the text to the server as UTF-8. But the line breaks (<w:br/>) in the runs are not resolving. They are being sent as empty square characters (□) and are coming back as black diamond question marks (�).

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00A739D5" w:rsidRDefault="00A739D5" w:rsidP="00A739D5">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cs="Calibri"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cs="Calibri"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:br/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cs="Calibri"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:br/>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Under "Default Web Site" you </w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

When I look at what's being sent, I see...

"□□Under “Default Web Site” you"

When I look at what's being returned, I see...

"��Under “Default Web Site” you"

When I search for the text, not surprisingly, I get 0 results.

```
searchResults = context.document.body.search(myText, { matchCase: true, ignorePunct: true, ignoreSpace:true});
```

Is this due to the rFonts attributes w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" and w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" ?

If so, what can I do to properly resolve these characters? Do I need to determine the styles being used in the document, first, then convert the text of the range before sending to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Word's "new line" character is ANSI 11. Most likely, the recipient on the server does not know what to do with this character, is interpreting it as best it can, and returning a string to Word with a character Word, in its turn, is unable to interpret correctly.

Best might be to replace this element with something when sending the string out and replace it when the string returns with ANSI 11.